# How to get many-to-many relationship data using pivot table

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.5, eloquent-relationship

I have below models:

```php
1. Campaign
2. Coupon
3. CampaignCoupon
```

`CampaignCoupon` is model of pivot table for many to many relationship of `Campaign` and `Coupon`.

I have below relationship in `CampaignCoupon` model:

```php
public function coupons() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Coupon', 'campaign_coupon','campaign_id','coupon_id');         
}

public function campaigns() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Campaign', 'campaign_coupon','campaign_id','coupon_id');
}
```

In request I get `coupon_id` and `campaign_id` now i want to get `Coupon` and `Campaign` data using `CampaignCoupon` model.

Here is query I have used:

```php
$CampaignCoupon = CampaignCoupon::where('campaign_id', $input['campaign_id'])
    ->where('coupon_id', $input['coupon_id'])
    ->with(['coupons', 'campaigns']) 
    ->first();
```

But it returns null array of coupons and campaign.

```php
{"id":95,"campaign_id":21,"coupon_id":25,"max_usage":21,"coupons":[],"campaigns":[]}
```

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this relationship instead of yours

```
public function coupons() {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Coupon','coupon_id');   
           } 
public function campaigns() {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Campaign','campaign_id');   
           }
```